# box decoration break не работает в safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, scss, safari

для субтитров в видео используются
box-decoration-break: clone;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
в ff и google chrome все работает как надо. в safari обрезаются, будто box decoration игнорируются. Как это исправить?
видео плеер videoJs. для отключения нативных субтитров используется
html5: {
nativeTextTracks: false,
},
safari
[image: SAFARI]

chrome, ff
[image: chrome, ff]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.